# libvlc+qwidget handle mouse event on Win64

Tags: mouseevent, qwidget, libvlc, win64

I am working on Qt and using libVlc version 2.1.5 for live video streaming.I want to handle mouse press event on vlc frame.But when I click on vlc,it is not able to throw the mouse event.
I have tried with

```
libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(libvlcMediaPlayer,false);
```

But it hides the mouse over vlc.
Please help me if anyone knows.

Thanks.

Comment: Before 'libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(libvlcMediaPlayer,false);' it is showing mouse information on console and With 'libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(libvlcMediaPlayer,false);' it is not showing any mouse information on console.

Comment: I've used mouse hooks to solve same task at Vlc Web Plugins: http://git.videolan.org/?p=npapi-vlc.git;a=blob;f=common/win32_fullscreen.cpp;hb=HEAD - but it little bit complex.

Comment: Another possible solution could be use QtQuick with my libvlc wrapper library: https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlc You could look mouse events handling demo for WebChimera Plugin: http://www.webchimera.org/demos/mouse_events - it uses QmlVlc library under the hood. You could ask any related questions at https://gitter.im/RSATom/WebChimera

Comment: RSATom , thanks for replying , but I am not able to got your point.I tried to whatever you said but not able to understand.Is I need to add extra plugin to our class.I am creating desktop based application with LIBVLC .

Comment: Ok, let me ask you question: Are you ready use QML/QtQuick in your application?

Comment: Actually I have never worked on QML/QtQuick.I am simply working on Qt 4.8 and creating desktop application.

Comment: Oh... then you have only one option - use Mouse Hooks. QmlVlc require Qt 5.x, but it allow handle mouse events over video with ease...

Comment: Thanks RSATom for your concern.I will try for this.

Comment: But no, you have one else option - decode video frames to memory (via so called vmem module) and draw them yourself on widget. Then you could handle mouse events as usual. But don't sure what will be simpler for you...

Comment: I have tried with mouse hook that you have provided , it is to much complex,Not able to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use libvlc_video_set_key_input function as well:

```
libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(media_player, 0);
libvlc_video_set_key_input(media_player, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Three Solutions on Windows

### Solution One: `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`

**Note**: May not work on `Windows 7` or below.

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/2/10 23:31
import vlc
import win32con
import win32gui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore


def togglePlaying():
    player.get_state() == vlc.State.Ended and player.set_media(player.get_media())
    player.get_state() == vlc.State.Playing and player.pause()
    player.get_state() != vlc.State.Playing and player.play()


def onVideoOut(event):
    hwnd = win32gui.GetWindow(player.get_hwnd(), win32con.GW_CHILD)
    exStyle = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
    exStyle |= win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())
window.centralWidget().mousePressEvent = lambda *args: togglePlaying()
window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowCloseButtonHint)
window.resize(854, 480)
window.show()

filename = r"https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
player = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename)
player.set_hwnd(window.centralWidget().winId())
player.event_manager().event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerVout, onVideoOut)
player.play()

app.exec_()
```

### Solution Two: Low-Level Mouse Hook

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/2/10 23:31
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE, c_int, Structure, cast, POINTER, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import LPARAM, WPARAM, DWORD, PULONG, LONG

import vlc
import win32con
import win32gui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore


def genStruct(name="Structure", **kwargs):
    return type(name, (Structure,), dict(
        _fields_=list(kwargs.items()),
        __str__=lambda self: "%s(%s)" % (name, ",".join("%s=%s" % (k, getattr(self, k)) for k in kwargs))
    ))


@WINFUNCTYPE(LPARAM, c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM)
def hookProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    msg = cast(lParam, POINTER(HookStruct))[0]
    hwnd = win32gui.WindowFromPoint((msg.pt.x, msg.pt.y))
    if hwnd in vlcHwnds:
        win32gui.PostMessage(widget.winId(), wParam, wParam, (msg.pt.y << 16) + msg.pt.x)
    return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(None, nCode, WPARAM(wParam), LPARAM(lParam))


def togglePlaying():
    print("toggle")
    player.get_state() == vlc.State.Ended and player.set_media(player.get_media())
    player.get_state() == vlc.State.Playing and player.pause()
    player.get_state() != vlc.State.Playing and player.play()


def onVideoOut(event):
    hwnd1 = win32gui.GetWindow(player.get_hwnd(), win32con.GW_CHILD)
    hwnd2 = win32gui.GetWindow(hwnd1, win32con.GW_CHILD)
    vlcHwnds.append(hwnd1)
    vlcHwnds.append(hwnd2)
    print("vlcHwnds", vlcHwnds)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widget.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda *args: togglePlaying()
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(widget)
window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowCloseButtonHint)
window.resize(854, 480)
window.show()
vlcHwnds = []

HookStruct = genStruct(
    "Hook", pt=genStruct("Point", x=LONG, y=LONG), mouseData=DWORD, flags=DWORD, time=DWORD, dwExtraInfo=PULONG)
msgDict = {v: k for k, v in win32con.__dict__.items() if k.startswith("WM_")}
windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL, hookProc, None, 0)

filename = r"https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
player = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename)
player.set_hwnd(widget.winId())
player.event_manager().event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerVout, onVideoOut)
player.play()
app.exec_()
```

### Solution Three: In-Process Mouse Hook

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/2/10 23:31
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE, c_int, Structure, cast, POINTER, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import LPARAM, WPARAM, DWORD, PULONG, LONG, HINSTANCE

import vlc
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore


def genStruct(name="Structure", **kwargs):
    return type(name, (Structure,), dict(
        _fields_=list(kwargs.items()),
        __str__=lambda self: "%s(%s)" % (name, ",".join("%s=%s" % (k, getattr(self, k)) for k in kwargs))
    ))


@WINFUNCTYPE(LPARAM, c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM)
def hookProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    msg = cast(lParam, POINTER(HookStruct))[0]
    win32gui.PostMessage(widget.winId(), wParam, wParam, (msg.pt.y << 16) + msg.pt.x)
    return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(None, nCode, WPARAM(wParam), LPARAM(lParam))


def togglePlaying():
    player.get_state() == vlc.State.Ended and player.set_media(player.get_media())
    player.get_state() == vlc.State.Playing and player.pause()
    player.get_state() != vlc.State.Playing and player.play()


def onVideoOut(event):
    hwnd1 = win32gui.GetWindow(player.get_hwnd(), win32con.GW_CHILD)
    processId = win32api.GetModuleHandle()
    threadId = windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd1, None)
    windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE, hookProc, HINSTANCE(processId), threadId)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widget.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda *args: togglePlaying()
window.setCentralWidget(widget)
window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowCloseButtonHint)
window.resize(854, 480)
window.show()

HookStruct = genStruct(
    "Hook", pt=genStruct("Point", x=LONG, y=LONG), mouseData=DWORD, flags=DWORD, time=DWORD, dwExtraInfo=PULONG)
msgDict = {v: k for k, v in win32con.__dict__.items() if k.startswith("WM_")}
filename = r"https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
player = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename)
player.set_hwnd(widget.winId())
player.event_manager().event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerVout, onVideoOut)
player.play()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used libvlc 2.2.2 under Ubuntu 16 and managed to get mouse events on vlc video area in following way (providing only code relevant to the issue). In my VideoPlayer class I have members:

```
libvlc_media_player_t* vlcPlayer;
VideoWidget* widget;
```

, where VideoWidget is my custom widget class. In cpp I set `libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(vlcPlayer, false);`, create `widget` instance, pass it to my UI and when "play" video is called i also pass widget to vlc `libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow(vlcPlayer, widget->winId());`

My custom VideoWidget class is following:

```
// header
class VideoWidget : public QFrame
{
public:
  VideoWidget(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR);

protected:
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
};

// cpp
VideoWidget::VideoWidget(QWidget* parent)
  : QFrame(parent)
{
}

void VideoWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
  qDebug() << "mouse press";
  QFrame::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

So the idea is to catch mouse events with QWidget passed to vlc.