# Capture click event on the screen of vlc in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, vlc

I am running a stripped down version of [the python-vlc example for tkinter](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/tkvlc.py) on Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

I am trying to register clicks onto the video screen itself, without any buttons or additional UI.
However, no matter where I try to .bind() a listener, VLC appears to swallow all input and my callback function is never called.

This is probably way too much code to post here, but at least it should run. Any help appreciated!

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vlc, sys, os, time, platform
import Tkinter as Tk
import ttk

def onClick():
    print "a click was successful!"

class Player(Tk.Frame):
    """The main window has to deal with events.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, title=None, url=""):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.url = url

        self.player = None
        self.videopanel = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.canvas = Tk.Canvas(self.videopanel,bg="blue")

        #try to listen for clicks
        self.videopanel.bind('<Button-1>', onClick)
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', onClick)

        self.canvas.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH,expand=1)
        self.videopanel.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH,expand=1)

        # VLC player controls
        self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()

        self.parent.update()

        self.Media = self.Instance.media_new(self.url)
        self.player.set_media(self.Media)

        # set the window id where to render VLC's video output
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            self.player.set_hwnd(self.GetHandle())
        else:
            self.player.set_xwindow(self.GetHandle()) # this line messes up windows

        self.player.play()

    def GetHandle(self):
        return self.videopanel.winfo_id()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk.Tk()

    player = Player(root, title="tkinter vlc", url="video.mp4")
    player.bind('<Button-1>', onClick)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding to the root frame?

```
root.bind('<Button-1>', onClick)
```

Your onClick function will need to accept the event as its first argument:

```
def onClick(e):
     print "a click was successful!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the `tkinter` question, this is the `libvlc` question.

`VLC` will create its own `HWND` handle above your video widget.

So you should make the `VLC` widget transparent for mouse events.

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71067838/5254103